# Android read from keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, listener, rfid

I have this logon screen with no textfields at all. When the user scans his id token with RFID scanner, i'll get a 8 character long string. Its the same principle as using an keyboard(just faster). I want my login activity to act, when the user has scanned his token and not before. Is there a smart way implementing this? I can't have any button or textfields, so I have to read keyboard input without listening to a EditText field.

So, an empty screen with an image(lock), that listens to an RFID reader(or keyboard) and act when the character count is 8.

Comment: implement `onKeyDown` like in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible listening to the keyboard without having an listener on a text field. Cause mu actual problem is, that i need the user to type in an 8 char long key. There should not be any text fields in the layout, nothing... imagine a blind user. I simple want to listen at any input from the user and manually save the input in my code. The layout will only contain a picture of a lock. I've tried EditText with your example, but i cant make the field unvisible without loosing its function.

Answer (score 8):

If you implement `onKeyDown()` in your `Activity` and there is no other UI widget that handles key events you should get every key press from your keyboard. Below example should work for A-Z at least and is intended to simply "print" the keypresses to a `TextView`.

You might need to add a more sophisticated way to map keycode to character if that is not enough. (e.g. space does not work, numbers probably neither)

```
public class KeyActivity extends Activity {
    // should work for a-z
    private static final Pattern KEYCODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("KEYCODE_(\\w)");

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // there is just a TextView, nothing that handle keys
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        String key = KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode);
        // key will be something like "KEYCODE_A" - extract the "A"

        // use pattern to convert int keycode to some character
        Matcher matcher = KEYCODE_PATTERN.matcher(key);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            // append character to textview
            mTextView.append(matcher.group(1));
        }
        // let the default implementation handle the event
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```