# How to detect continually key event on Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an Android device with an integrated barcode reader. So I want to write the code into a `Label` whenever a barcode is read.

In other words, how to capture a `key press` event (for example) without having a text input focused?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038440/android-read-from-keyboard

Comment: What's the barcode reader? Usually you can listen to an internal port that the scanned data is written to.

Comment: It is an integrated barcode reader in CipherLAB RS31 device. @Alex T.

Comment: @E.Williams Does the app come with an app that controls the scanner? If so, you should be able to go in and configure a scanning profile where you can export barcode data to an internal port. Then you'd just need to write a threaded listener for data sent to that port.

Comment: @AlexT. yes, there is an app to configure the scanner. But it only offers me the possibility of configure the format output and other irrelevant stuff... Do you know how can I guess which port is it using to transfer data?

Comment: @E.Williams That sounds like the right place. Like, you need to set up so that the scanner can work even whilst your app is running, for one thing. So there might be an option for _associated apps_. You should go through every option in the menu and see what's available to be exploited!

Comment: Impossible, it has no options refering to that :(

Comment: @E.Williams What is the app called?

Comment: `readerconfig`, its an app done by cipherlabs